# What's the best notation for a list of excluded values?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Suppose I was asked for the domain of $\frac{1}{x(x-1)(x-2)}$. What would be the best way to notate this? Here are some thoughts:

- $x\in \mathbb{R}$; $x \neq 0, 1, 2$
- $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $x \neq 0$ and $x \neq 1$ and $x \neq 2$
- $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $x \not\in \{0, 1, 2\}$

Going for clear, simple, and common.

Comment: Either the first or third is fine.  The second one is a little redundant.

Comment: You're describing the elements of the domain. I would denote the domain as $\mathbb{R} - \{0,1,2\}$ or $\mathbb{R} \smallsetminus \{0,1,2\}$.

Comment: @JairTaylor The commas always got to me. Especially when there was also an inclusive statement such as $x > -1$. Do the commas mean "and" or "or"? Seems vague to me.

Comment: @Elem-Teach-w-Bach-n-Math-Ed Well, "$x \neq 0$ or $x \neq 1$"  would describe all real numbers, so it's pretty clear from context that it means 'and'. But yes if you want to be more clear then #3 or Brian's choice above would be better.

Comment: $\Bbb C\setminus\{0,1,2\}$ ;)

Comment: One more: assuming a $f(x)$ is a Real function to address Stéphane's comment, what's the best way to express the domain of the function $f(x) =\frac{\sqrt{x^2-4}}{x-4}$